# Flexbox - weird content overflows on specific widths

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, word-wrap

Take a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TMCDOS/pen/NWBgZLx)
The text in the 3rd panel (`Spelling`) overflows without any obvious reason - both on Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

I don't know if it is related - but the 2nd panel (`Quiz: Leapfrog`) takes more space horizontally than is needed for its contents - about 15-16 pixels:

[image]

If you play with the inline style of the card and change the `max-width:` from **478px** to **470px** and below, or to **511px** and above - the overflow goes away.

[image]

---

May I get some help in understanding why this weird overflow happens and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `flex-basis: 0 /* or 50% in your case could also work */` on your 3 items to help flex understand how things work together.

Have you tried to use css `display: grid;`?
Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: 350px;
  height: 160px;
  background: #fafafa;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "first first"
    "second third";
}

.child {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#child1 {
  background: #0e6376;
  grid-area: first;
}

#child2 {
  background: #f9b4af;
  grid-area: second;
}

#child3 {
  background: #f15c3b;
  grid-area: third;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child" id="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child" id="child2">child2</div>
  <div class="child" id="child3">child3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately neither of your suggestions works in my case. CSS grid will have the same number of columns in each row - but in my usecase some rows will have just one 1 panel and other rows will have 2 or even 3 panels, depending on their actual size. That's why I use `flex-wrap`. Setting a `flex-basis: 0` will make all panels on a given row to have equal width, which is not desired. The widths depend on the content.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after more than 3 hours of scratching my head and no help from anyone I suddenly and out of nowhere decided to set a `min-width` on the white squares which contain the icons:

```css
.activity_icon
{
  border-radius: inherit;
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  min-width: 60px; /* <==== added */
  height: 60px;
}
```

And voila - the Flexbox parent now properly wraps the Flexbox children.